# Better visualization of a vertical bar plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, bar-chart, graph-visualization

Y have a huge RDD from spark that contains the logs  of server requests to our server. I want to visualize the requests per day in a period of time; for better visualization I decided to use a vertical bar chart showing the dates on the y axis and the #requests in the x-axis. The code I have is as follows:

```
keys = list(frequencies.keys())
vals = list(frequencies.values())

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

ax.barh(np.arange(len(keys)),vals)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(keys)))
ax.set_yticklabels(keys)
ax.invert_yaxis()   
ax.set_xlabel('day')
ax.set_ylabel('requests')
```

This is my resulting plot:

[image]

So, as you can see, I can't visualize the dates at all. Is there a way to extend the y-axis so the dates become visible?.

Comment: Does `fig.tight_layout()` work out for you?

Comment: I just tried it, but no, I still have the same problem.

Comment: Are you able to show how you would want it to look?

Comment: You have to put the statement at the end of your code. Also, try removing `ax.invert_yaxis()`

Comment: Good question.. I mean, al those black bars that represent dates I want to see them in a vertical line, it doesn't matter how high it get.